# Find size of largest document in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to find out what the size of the largest document in my cluster is?

I've tried the `GET /_stats`, but there only seems to be information about the amount of documents and the total amount of space they take up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not natively. You can install the mapper size plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size.html and get this information, but otherwise it is not tracked.